# Woo commerce WP - Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Please help me guys! I got this error at [this page](http://mycasable.com/new-arrivals/?v=75dfaed2dded). You may inspect element to see the error. My menu dropdown function has been disabled. You scroll to accessories and inspect element, there is an error about `uncaught referenceerror: ga is not defined`. However in my homepage it works fine. Please help me.

Woo Commerce JavaScript

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    ga('ec:addImpression', { // Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
        'id': '19013',
        'name': 'Portable Karaoke Player Wireless Bluetooth Speaker Microphone #2',
        'category': 'Others/Others (Brands)/Portable Microphone',
        'list': 'Product List',
        'position': 1
    });
```

Comment: Please help me guys! I got this error at this page. https://mycasable.com/new-arrivals/?v=75dfaed2dded (you may inspect element to see the error) my menu dropdown function has been disabled. You scroll to accessories(and inspect element) there is an error about uncaught referenceerror: ga is not defined) But in my homepage it works fine. Please help me!!! *note: I'm a beginner in website design and I only know minimal about coding*

Comment: In future, please use the `edit` button to add more detail to your question. I've done it for you in this case.

Comment: The error implies that you haven't include Google Analytics in the page properly. At the very least it's not being loaded. Check the console for errors

Comment: Google Analytics JS is missing

Comment: Thankyou @RoryMcCrossan for helping me to edit and answer my question. Yeah it seems that google analytics js has been missed out. I've corrected it. REALLY THANKYOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR SWIFT RESPONSE!!!

Comment: @farscode thankyou! I've figured out how to solve it! Thanks alot!